# My Vue App doesn't load on using multiple conditions in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ternary

in a weather displaying app I used to learn Vue
This is the original expression on which the app works fine

```
<div id="app" :class="typeof weather.main != 'undefined' && weather.main.temp < 16 ? '' : 'warm' ">
```

but when I change the expression to -

```
<div id="app" :class="typeof weather.main != 'undefined' && weather.main.temp < 16 ? '' : weather.main.temp < 18 ?'chill': weather.main.temp < 30 ?'warm':'hot' ">
```

the app compiles but it doesn't load anything and the console is blank no errors.

Comment: It's a logic issue: In the original code, if `weather.main` is `undefined`, it shows `warm` (which is probably a bug). In your updated code, it tries to evaluate `weather.main.temp < 18` but `weather.main` is `undefined`, so it fails with an error. (I don't know why you're not seeing an error in the console.) The first condition should be `typeof weather.main === "undefined" || weather.main.temp < 16`. (It probably always should have been that.)

Comment: But I strongly recommend **not** using nested conditional expressions inline like that. Instead, determine what class you want to show with a variable ahead of time (probably with `if`/`else if` rather than nested conditional expressions, but at least if it's in code you can format the nested conditionals in a readable way if you do want to use them), and then use that variable to set the class.

Comment: Thanks that worked I was just adding new conditions to test around more cases and will keep your advice in mind of not using the conditional expressions the way I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [operator precendece](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The expression is evaluated as

```
(typeof weather.main != 'undefined' && weather.main.temp < 16) ? '' : (weather.main.temp < 18 ?'chill': weather.main.temp < 30 ?'warm':'hot')
```

This results in `weather.main.temp < 18` being evaluated when `weather.main` is undefined.

The solution is to not put unreadable code into the template and move it to computed property where it can be written in a form that is easy to comprehend and maintain. `typeof` check for undefined values is needed only for potentially undefined variables. Optional chaining can be used in computed properties in Vue 2 to avoid condition checks, as well as in templates in Vue 3.

It can be:

```
computed: {
  appClass() {
    if (!weather.main || weather.main.temp < 16)
      return '';
    else if (weather.main.temp < 18)
      return 'chill';
    else if (weather.main.temp < 30)
      return 'warm';
    else 
      return 'hot';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it really helped me out. and I will make the necessary changes

Comment: It's not really a precedence issue. The initial condition in the original code in the question (the first code block) is basically just wrong. If you correct it, there's no precedence issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It looks like the OP meant it to be `typeof weather.main != 'undefined' && (...)`, hence the mention of precedence. Or it could be just wrong, I've got no [mindreading] badge yet.

Comment: (Amusingly I read that as "min-dreading" and it took me a long time to see it the other way.) I see what you're saying there, but the *original* code used `"warm"` instead of `""` in the undefined case, which looks and smells like a bug. :-) If you fix that (`typeof weather.main === "undefined" || weather.main.temp < 16`), there's no precedence issue. But completely agreed on moving that out of the `:class` entirely, and avoiding a nested conditional for it. :-)